Octave: audiowrite exports to 32 bits instead of 24
I wrote a simple program for normalizing audio. The original file is 24 bits.
I checked the bits after exporting and it said 32 instead of 24.
Files=dir(fullfile(pwd,'*.wav'))

    fsize = size(Files)
    fsize = fsize(1)

    for i = 1:fsize
        name = Files(i).name
        [A,Fs]=audioread(name) ;

        oms = sqrt (meansq (A(:)))
        A_new=A*0.05/oms;

        audiowrite(['n_',name],A_new,Fs,'BitsPerSample',24)
    endfor

I tried this on 6.4.0 and 9.1.0 version and both versions did the same thing. I used MediaInfo to check the bits and it said 32. The default option for exporting is 16 bits, so you definitely need to specify the number of bits.
Do you know what could be causing this?

That's for compatibility with matlab, see bug #45490

I also changed the output to PCM32 when Bits Per Sample is 24 for compatibility with Matlab.

24 generates int32 wav. 32 generates float32 wav.
